# install-package Visual Studio "Dependecy Loop Detected"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-package

I wanted to reference an old version of **newtonsoft.json** to my project but package manager is telling my there is a 'loop'. I have already uninstalled **newtonsoft.json** and it confirms that I no longer have it.

[Dependecy Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXCdz.png)

Edit: I have 2 projects in my solution. I want add an older version of 9.0 in Project B.

Project A references
 Newtonsoft.Json 9.0

Project B references
 Project A

Update 2: The Package manager UI gives me the latest one that is why I am trying to use the console.

Can anyone share some light to what really is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: What's the result if you install the package using Nuget Package Manager UI? Right-click project in Solution Explorer=>Manage nuget packages to install the package to your current project. As for the loop, how many projects are there in your solution, and what's the relationship between them?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Is there a way to install a specific version via the Nuget Package Manager UI? I need the older version. The UI gives me the the latest one. As for the relationship. I have 2 projects, 1 is dependent in version 9.0 and the one I want the dll to be added.

Comment: Yes, you can install the specific version by Pakcage Manager UI, and it works from VS2015 to VS2019, But I'm not sure if it has same function in old versions. Can I know what vs version do you use?

Comment: Seems I am using v2 so I updated it now. I just renewed the solution to cleanup any left over dependencies and that seem to have fixed my issue. Thanks for the help. Not sure what was causing the loop problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS,go `Tools=>Options=>Package Manager(Nuget Package Manager)=>Package Source` to check your `available package source`, make sure you've configured and enabled `Nuget.org(v3)` there, if not, configure it manually to add it as `package source`.

[image]

Then in `package manager` I suggest you can use command `Install-Package NewtonSoft.json -Version 9.0.1` to install the package current project.

If you still get the `Dependency Loop` error message, assuming you have three project in the solution, A depends on B, B depends on C. And B is the project you want to install Newtonsoft 9.0.1 package, check if A have a nuget package requires higher version than 9.0.1, or if C have a package requires higher version than 9.0.1.

Comment: Not sure if this resolved it but I cleaned up the whole solution/project and started a new one. Then updated to v3. Seem to have worked.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help :)